# How I can make authentication using my own class in laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm trying to do a basic authentication which considers email and password. My problem comes when I call the method `Auth :: attempt` I get the following error.

[image]

**Model**

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'Usuario';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idUsuario';
    protected $fillable = array('Nombre', 
                            'Apellido', 
                            'TipoUsuario', 
                            'Contrasena', 
                            'Correo', 
                            'Telefono');
}
```

**Controller**

```
class UsuarioController extends BaseController{
    public function doLogin(){
        $rules = array('correo' => 'required|email',
                        'contrasena' => 'required');

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('usuario')
                    ->withErrors($validator)// manda los errores al login
                    ->withInput(Input::except('contrasena')); //

        }else{
            $userData = array(
                        'Correo' => Input::get('correo'),
                        'Contrasena' => Input::get('contrasena')
                        );

            if(Auth::attempt($userData)){
                echo 'bien';
            }else{
                return Redirect::to('login');
            }
        }
    }

    public function showLogin(){
        return View::make('login');
    }
}
```

**Routte**

```
Route::get('usuario', array('uses' => 'UsuarioController@showLogin'));
Route::post('usuario', array('uses' => 'UsuarioController@doLogin'));
```

**Auth.php**

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'database',
    'model' => 'User',
    'table' => 'Usuario',
    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of checking user credentials `Laravel` calls `validateCredentials` method when `Auth::attempt` gets called and in this function (given below) `Laravel` checks for the `password` key in the passed array and in your case you are not passing a `password` key so the error happens.

```
public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

Change the `key` in the `$userData` array:

```
$userData = array(
    'email' => Input::get('correo'), // If correo means email
    'password' => Input::get('contrasena') // If contrasena means password
);
```

Also make changes in your database table's field names which represents `users` table, I think it's your `Usuario` table.

Comment: if I change ``Correo`` for ``email`` apper ``SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Usuario` where `email` = zhelon@algo.com limit 1)``, but if I quick it the same way it work but if I change ``Contrasena`` for ``password`` apper a new error ``/**
  * Get the password for the user.
  *
  * @return string
  */
 public function getAuthPassword()
 {
  return $this->attributes['password'];
 }`` in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser.php

Comment: Did you read the last line in my answer ? `Also make changes in your database table's field names which represents users`. You need to change the field names in your `Usuario` table as well otherwise there is no such a column/field.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check to make sure you're passing the correct info to Auth::attempt() in your controller.  I use something more like:

```
$userData = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));
```

Comment: If I do that apper ``SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Usuario` where `email` = zhelon@algo.com limit 1)``